# systemd service script for libreoffice/openoffice

Tags: systemd, startup, openoffice

I'm trying to setup correctly a **headless** libreoffice/openoffice server on a debian jessie. I created a script named /etc/systemd/system/openoffice.service with the following content

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenOffice service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/soffice '--accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8101;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager' --headless --nofirststartwizard --nologo
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all
User=www-data

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I enabled it via:

```
systemctl enable openoffice.service
```

I'm in a situation that is only partially working:

- it correctly starts on boot
- if queried status `systemctl status openoffice.service` it clams it is still activating
- If I try to start it it just hangs

I haven't been able to find a working example, I'd also like to understand how to create the debian /etc/init.d script that uses systems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `Type=notify` in your service. This is meant to be used only for specific services which are [designed to notify systemd when they have finished starting up](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). At the moment, these are rather uncommon, and I don't think LibreOffice is among them.

You should most likely be using `Type=simple` instead.